Mining metals with microbes
Before about 1985, I read a novel about a space colony on a desperately metal-poor world. The story turned on a radical idea to use genetic engineering to create microbes that could mine effectively. There were at least two books. Please identify the story.
This is interesting because there have recently been patents issued to do with almost exactly this as part of ISRU for Mars.

Mining metals with non-genetically engineered microbes isn't even science fiction. The Primitive Technology vlogging dude makes stuff with bacterial iron frequently. Welcome to SFF.SE, ClintFromVa!

Also see The geomicrobiology of gold. TLDR: It's likely that gold concentration by bacteria is a major process in the formation of gold deposits.

Bacteria were used in the (locally) infamous Talvivaara mine

This is Sylvia Engdahl's Children of the Star trilogy, particularly the third book The Doors of the Universe, published in 1981.
The settlers on a metal-poor world are stuck there... barely surviving on the metal they brought, dependent upon it to grow grain, to filter water, to live.  For years they nursed the hope of creating metal via advanced physics, but now even that hope is fading.
The priest Noren is driven to study the dead field of genetics after the death of his wife.  He realized that rather than using machines to render the world's poisons inert, he could adjust the genome of the settlers to metabolize the toxins instead.  He sets the world on a path of genetic change to ensure the survival of the species.
After finding a hint from an advanced species, he learns to use genetic engineering to process trace metal elements and, essentially, farm metal.  The doors of the universe are thrown back open as the settlers glean enough metal to rebuild their spaceships.

...Noren explained his discovery. The metal could be extracted from
lake water and wet soil, not by any method the Founders had known, but
by genetically altered bacteria - which was, no doubt, a routine
process on worlds less rich in ore than the Six.  For it had been
suggested to him not by sheer genius, but by a new alien artifact
found the previous year near Futurity.


Many thanks!  Now off to find a copy...  it is always so cool when fiction becomes fact.  Shades of Jules Vern!

@ClintFromVa check out her web site (the book links above go to it); she's got her ebooks affordably priced at Smashwords.com.
